# CakePHP: error views from plugin

Tags: cakephp, view

I'm trying, for my app, to use views error from a plugin. So, the error views can be found here:

```
app/Plugin/MyPlugin/View/Errors/
```

Instead, I would use the layout from the application ("default.ctp" or better "error.ctp"). Only the error views should be taken from the plugin.

I tried, but I could not find any examples, and I understand that I maybe have to rewrite the ExceptionRenderer class, but I have not found good examples. Can anyone give me some tips?

Thanks

Comment: After many months, I still have this problem and I haven't yet found a solution.
Quite simply: it seems useless create error views for each application. So I would like to create a single plugin with common error views. How to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```
class MyExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {
    /**
     * Generate the response using the controller object.
     * @param string $template The template to render.
     */
    protected function _outputMessage($template) {
        $template = sprintf('%s.%s', 'MyPlugin', $template);

        parent::_outputMessage($template);
    }
}
```